# Is NLog archive feature available for custom target

Tags: c#, nlog

I have create a custom NLog target that outputs customized JSON log file using a third-party SDK. I want to use NLog's archive feature to archive the JSON files, but is unable to do so.

I have tried having my custom NLog target to inherit from NLog's FileTarget class, and using "archiveAboveSize" attribute in the target's element inside the NLog config file. However, NLog seems to ignore the attribute and does not report any error in its internal log file.

```
<target xsi:type="CustomTarget" name="MyCustomTarget" 
archiveAboveSize="1000"
FileName="C:\temp\customLog.json" />
```

I expect the customLog.json file to be archived whenever its size hits 1KB, but no archiving is done when the file size hits 1KB or above.

Comment: Instead of creating a custom NLog Target, then you should create a custom NLog LayoutRenderer that can be used in the NLog FileTarget. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-layout-renderer

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @RolfKristensen, however, I was hoping to find a way to enable file archiving on my custom Target as I already have the Target working. Still, I will take a look at the custom LayoutRenderer and see what it offers.